# How can I calculate font size of UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

For instance, in Photoshop I have font of label 30px (for retina display).
What font size should I have for that? 
if I set 15, it's too small.
How can I calculate?

Comment: Yes you need to set it as 15. It will double the size in retina display. What is the issue??

Comment: check there PhotoShop font of lable are px or pt that both are different make sure please about it.

Comment: I think the confusion on your question is from how font sizes are measured. You're probably measuring from the top of the highest symbol to the bottom of the lowest. Font sizes are measured from the highest possible point, not just the one you used. If you measure `Ñj` in photoshop from top to bottom and use that font size in iOS, it should be the same size on a non-retina display (divide the height by 2 for retina displays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right and you need to set font size 15 pixel in non retina display. If your photoshop font setting in pixel.

Comment: Any one can tell me reason for downvote ? That will be better for me in future.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because he already stated that 15 is too small..

Comment: +1 I don't know who gave you downvote.